# Adding a tag handler to a JSF 2.1 composite component

Tags: java, jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

I have a custom component

```
<composite:interface>       
    <composite:attribute name="var"></composite:attribute>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
 <h:dataTable var="#{cc.attrs.var}">                     
    <composite:insertChildren/>
 </h:dataTable>
</composite:implementation>
```

that doesn't work because the dataTable var attribute doesn't accept EL expressions.
How to solve this? I found an old solution that proposed to write a custom TagHandler to handle the component but I don't really know how to attach it to my custom component.

Comment: What do you except to pass to your composite component through that var attribute? May it should value instead of var, you use var to refer to current row (or element in the list) from within the dataTable in the column.